# Htaccess rewriting url make slash(/) optionional

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this htaccess url rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?login/?(.*)/(.*)$ /admin/index\.php?username=%1&m=$1&page=$2
```

These are the test cases I followed.

```
admin.mysite.com

admin.mysite.com/login

admin.mysite.com/login/

admin.mysite.com/login/0

admin.mysite.com/login/0/

admin.mysite.com/login/0/clients
```

In the above test cases, these were successful.

```
admin.mysite.com

admin.mysite.com/login/

admin.mysite.com/login/0/

admin.mysite.com/login/0/clients
```

Other URLs are displaying a 404 error. I realized "slash" is the reason for this error. How can I make it optional in my htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate the different cases which makes things much easier to read and therefor easier to maintain for later modifications:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?login/?$ /admin/index\.php?username=%1 [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?login/(.*)/?$ /admin/index\.php?username=%1&m=$1 [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?login/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /admin/index\.php?username=%1&m=$1&page=$2 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).